# Git error : gpg failed to to sign the data only in VSCode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gnupg

I want to start to sign my commits using a GPG key on Codium (also tried on Code - OSS but I got the same error).
Here's the error I'm facing :

```
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

I've configured this :
`git config --global gpg.program gpg` or like that `git config --global gpg.program /usr/bin/gpg`

`git config --global user.signingkey <MY_SIGNING_KEY>`

I've also got this configured :
`git config --global commit.gpgsign true`

I put `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` in my .zshrc

I created `~/gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` file to put `pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-tty`

When I'm doing a "command line" commit `git commit -S -m "test"` it works fine.
But on **VSCode** it prompts me for the passphrase, then load indefinitely.

I'm kind of confused right now...

I'm on Arch btw :)

EDIT : Yes in VSCode settings, the line `Git: Enable Commit Signing` is checked

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

`gpgconf --kill gpg-agent`

After that I was able to commit fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had now exactly that issue and I did resolve it. I just have found out, that picked profile by VSCode's git plugin doesn't have signinkey (not sure why as previously it was working). So to resolve it:

- search for you key id `gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG`

```bash
/Users/your_user/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
------------------------------------------
sec   dsa3072/<key> 2023-07-04 [SC]
      <hash>
uid                 [ultimate] <gpg key name> (<user nick name>) <<email>>
```

- copy hash from `<key>`
- edit existing saved profile used by your VSCode
  `cmd+shift+p` > `git config user profiles: edit an existing user profile` > `pick your profile` > enter till the question `4/4` about signinkey where you put your `<key>` id

Now you should be able to use it properly.